# Zipcode validation remove extra numbers on keyup

Tags: jquery

ik have a input where a zipcode must be checked. This i what i have at the moment.

```
$("input[id='postal']").keyup(function count() {

    var zipcodeValue = this.value;
    zipcodeCheck = zipcodeValue.split(" ").join("");
    var regex = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}$/i);

    if (regex.test(zipcodeCheck) == true) {   
        // something
    } else {
        // something else
    }
});
```

This is working, but i want to disable user to type more than four numbers.
The zipcode must be like this 1234AB or 1234 AB but not 12345B.

Can i remove the fifth/sixth number when this is typed on keyup?

Thank you

Comment: Use `keydown` and `return false` if the user entered a fifth number (count the already typed in numbers. if the user typed in four numbers and the pressed one is also a number, return false)

Comment: Will it work using masked input: check the "demo" tab 

[link](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this - http://jsfiddle.net/bS9Q8/

```
$("#postal").keydown(function(e) {
    var zipcodeValue = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);;
    if (zipcodeValue.length<5) { return true;}
    var regex = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}$/i);
    if (zipcodeValue.length==5) {
        regex = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{4}[a-z]{1}$/i);
    }
    if (regex.test(zipcodeValue) != true) {   
        return false;        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try keydown event

```
$("input[id='postal']").keydown(function (event) {
 var zipcodeValue = this.value;
 zipcodeCheck = zipcodeValue.split(" ").join("");
 var regex = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}$/i);

 if (regex.test(zipcodeCheck) == true) {   
     // something
 } else {
     // something else
     return false;
 }

});
```

Comment: The idea is good but the example will not work because it will return false and you can't type anything

Comment: check `if(zipcodeValue.length>3)` and the last typed char is an integer return false no keyup